# find DIV HTML in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm using VS2010, C# to develop my ASP.NET web app, I've created a page dynamically (using several server side and HTML controls on the page). Now I'm going to send my page via email, I should have its content as HTML, how can I have my page HTML? of course I have a DIV (runat=....) which contains the parts which should be sent, how can I get its HTML content? `innerHTML` gives me not literal error, what are my options? I want to have the final rendered content of my DIV

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can render an webforms control in code using something like the following:

```
var control = new Control();
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(b));
control.RenderControl(writer);
return b.ToString();
```

NOTE: there is also another method to render the whole page which might be a bit easier than what has already been proposed:

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(url, writer);
string output = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

Comment: well if your div has a `runat="server"` tag that means that you can access it in your codebehind...  so just replace the `var control` object in my code with your DIV

Comment: I've got following error: Control 'imgFa' of type 'ImageButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: webforms need a HTML form element (hence the name) in order to work...  so the control needs to be placed inside a form tag on the markup page.  I would make sure that you can render everything okay in the browser before trying the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try simply downloading the page as a string using *WebClient*.

```
var wc = new WebClient();
string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;    // for the current page, otherwise set the URL
string html = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

Not sure if you're aware, but HTML emails are a tricky subject (email clients are like very crappy browsers, you can only use basic markup and CSS).  I'd recommend checking out [HTML Email Boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/) for some tips and best practices on this.